# How to create database using database first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

My application is ASP.NET MVC 4
I want to create database through database first approach.

Below is the my context class.

```
public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Below is web.config file:

```
             <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <!--
       For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
           -->

        <configuration>
  <appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

 <system.web>
   <roleManager enabled="true" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
  </compilation>

   <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
   </authentication> 

  <pages>
   <namespaces>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
     <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
   </namespaces>
  </pages>
 </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
        </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=finaldaCodeFirst;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>  
    </configuration>
```

Please guide me, why database was not created in sql server ?

what is missing here ?

Comment: Doesn't database first mean you design your database first then create your entities by mapping to the database article?

Comment: No, I have not designed database yet. But want to design through these models which are added as `dbset`.

Comment: That would be code-first then, unless I am missing something. Anyway, you can select right-click the entity you have designed in ef and select Generate database from model and then update the database as needed.

Comment: No, I have not added edmx file. I have just created context class and added dbset<modelclass>.. and same name as context class added connection string and expect to have database created.

Comment: I think you have to put that in your start-up code then. There is a function to check for the database and create one if it does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

First create the empty MusicStoreEntities.mdf file in App_folder, then
in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MusicStoreContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
 connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MusicStoreEntities.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

then make changes in Dbcontext class:

```
public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
{
      // MusicStoreContext use the same name in the connectionstring
      public MusicStoreEntities() : base("MusicStoreContext")
        {

        }

    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }


}
```

if you are updating the same project, then must update the database using 'Package Manager Console' ..